# Need a CMS for a church - sermons, galleries, front-end/simple editing

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm creating a site for a church (news, events, sermons(audio & video), group pages, etc.)

For many clients, I use Drupal, Joomla, or Wordpress - however, none of these will work in this scenario. I need the church administrators to be able to create layouts easily, etc, and not be bogged down in the number of features. Often for these types of clients, I use Joomla, but editing content in multiple areas can be confusing for clients (is it content, a component, or a module, etc.). Drupal is great for form based content submission, but the rest would be overkill for this client.

I was leaning towards concrete5 for it's simplicity of use for the end-user, but many of the concrete5 add-ons feel like the alpha/betas of other CMS's extensions/add-ons.

I was also tempted by Fork CMS, but it's fairly new and doesn't offer a lot in the way of customization abilities.

So what would be a good CMS that allows either front end editing, or the backend is intuitive - offers good solid extensions/add-ons, and is mature and sees regular updates.

Comment: What do you mean by layout?

Comment: @John - content layout - I like concrete5's ability to add blocks, regions, etc. on the fly through an easy front end process. The issue is that concrete5 add-ons (to get mp3/podcasting abilities) feel unfinished.

Comment: @Jason: Are you a developer? Perhaps you could polish them up and submit the patches.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some church projects on Drupal (they can give you ideas and some good tools to use).

Take a look at:

**OpenChurch**, this is a Drupal distribution with all that you can need, focused on churches needs. So just download and istall: http://openchurchsite.com/

**Group in Drupal for churches**: http://groups.drupal.org/churches

**Geeks & God (podcast and resources)**: geeksandgod.com/episode30

I and I know that Mustard Seed Media focus on making churches sites and have nice videocast, mustardseedmedia.com

There are good information about drupal for making churches sites.

Hope this can help :)